# datatable change cell value if filter criteria is not matching instead of hiding row

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I need help. I am working with data table filter, here column filter hide rows if record not found and need is instead of hiding row display cell empty(with - value) where records are not following criteria. let me know if i can give you more details.

Comment: Give some more info like the query you are running what kind of output you want.

Comment: So after filtering, you want to keep the same rowcount, but the td contents must be replaced with a '-'?

Comment: @P.Jairaj yes, refer this link. http://chenjidesigns.com/practut/performance.html. Here i have multiple columns with score and if criteria is not match only content will replace with "-".

Comment: @markpsmith yes and when filter is cleared or match it should show data. footer will be updated accordingly. that i have done with footer callback. Refer this link for design.  chenjidesigns.com/practut/performance.html

Comment: Are you using server-side data?

Comment: no it is javascript filters

Answer (score 0):

As you have not given any information about the structure of data you use to display the info, I have assumed the structure to be as the object *data* in the below code. The buttons in the html code change the criteria when ever clicked.

Hope it Helps!!

### Edited for Datables

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [
    ["name1", 24],
    ["name2", 54]
  ];
  var crit = 0;
  $("#crit1").click(function() {
    crit = 20;
    filter();
  });
  $("#crit2").click(function() {
    crit = 40;
    filter();
  });
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      "data": data,
      "columns": [{
        title: "Name"
      }, {
        title: "Score"
      }],
      "columnDefs": [{
        // The `data` parameter refers to the data for the cell (defined by the
        // `data` option, which defaults to the column being worked with, in
        // this case `data: 0`.
        "render": function(data, type, row) {
          if (data > crit)
            return data;
          else
            return "-";
        },
        "targets": 1
      }]
    });
  var filter = function() {
    table.clear().draw();
    table.rows.add(data); // Add new data
    table.columns.adjust().draw();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="button" id="crit1" value="20%" />
<input type="button" id="crit2" value="40%" />
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Useful links:

https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html

Comment: data structure is same and i have one constant value for each button and within range i am assigning constant value to cell respectively, is there any datatable functionality i can use for this filter. As i may need pagination and footer calculation, i think it will datatable will reduce my code and easy to handle.